# Changing conflicting assembly references

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, reference

My friend gave me a project created in Xamarin Studio. When I try to run the project I get some warnings related to conflicting assembly references.

I used the [AsmSpy](https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy) tool to check what references are conflicting and I got the following output:

```
Detailing only conflicting assembly references.
Reference: Newtonsoft.Json
    6.0.0.0 by Akavache     <-- this one is Green
    6.0.0.0 by Akavache.Sqlite3     <-- this one is Green
    8.0.0.0 by MyAppName     <-- this one is Red

Reference: Splat
    1.6.0.0 by Akavache
    1.6.0.0 by Akavache.Sqlite3
    1.6.2.0 by MyAppName
```

I never worked with Xamarin Studio and I lack some knowledge in this topic. How can I change the references to stop this warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an Assembly Redirect to 'bump' all assemblies to use a specific version.

(you will need to update name, publickey and versions accordingly)

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Akavache" publicKeyToken="1234567890" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

These need to be in your *.config file in the runtime node;

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```